# Using structure in structure..unable ot access inner structure elements?

Tags: c

Hi friend i am new and trying to learn structure...here i have declared structure date in structure calc...but not getting idea as how to access the elements from date. I have reserved memory by using malloc for parent structure calc..will that be sufficient for date structure as well? .please guide me...thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date{
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
};

struct calc{
   int row;
   int col;
   char menu_name[20];
   char sub_menu_name[20];
   struct date dob;
};

int main()
{
    int count = 0, i;
    struct calc *my_calc[2];

   //here unable to understand that where i need to resever seprate memory for date?
   my_calc[0] = (struct calc *)malloc(sizeof(struct calc)); 

   //trying to asign the date value 
   for(count; count<2; count++)
   {   
       printf("Please enter day: ");    
       scanf("%d",&my_calc[count]->date.day);

       printf("Please enter month: ");    
       scanf("%d",&my_calc[count]->date.month);

       printf("Please enter Year: ");    
       scanf("%d",&my_calc[count]->date.year);
   }

   //trying to print the date value 
   printf("Day: %d\t  Month: %d\t   Year: %d\n ",my_calc[0]->date.day,my_calc[0]->date.month,my_calc[0]->date.year);

   system("PAUSE");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you declare `dob` not `date`. `&my_calc[count]->dob.day`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am really becoming stupid...i will make sure that this will not repeat...sorry about that...tanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dob`, not `date`, for example:

```
scanf("%d",&my_calc[count]->dob.day);
```

The name of the element you want to access is `dob` - `date` is the structure name.

With this modification, your code compiles fine, but you will have some severe **runtime issues** - see the other answers on hints how to properly allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you malloc `sizeof(struct calc)` then that includes all elemets of that structs (read: it does a `sizeof` for all elements of the struct and sums that up and allocates space according).

I also see a lot of pointer/array issues within your code, you should really read up on that topic.

And you need to ref by the name of the element `dob`, not name of the strcut the element is of (`date`)